# How can I change the font in “Single A Theme” of Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, font

I'm using Single A Theme 1.3 for my Tumblr blog, but could not find the appropriate CSS code to change the font for posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Tumblr, click on your blog, and then click the Customize blog link. Within the customize pane, scroll down to Advanced and expand it. Within the “Add custom CSS” field, enter the following for the main font: `body {font-family: Arial;}` and the following for the secondary font: `.fS {font-family: Arial;}`. Arial is only being used as an example. Feel free to change it to whatever font you would like.